# Activity is destroyed and then recreated before receive onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My Activity has `Handler` object, and registers `ContentObserver` with this handler. Then I launch external activity, that may sometimes change content *(I use content observer to catch this alters)*.
Then activity returns result, and then I check my `observer`, if content was changed since I started that activity for result. Problem is that sometime, right before `onActivityResult`, my activity gets `onDestroy` - `onCreate`, and as result, everything I `catched` from observer is lost.

this Activity has following properties in AndroidManifest:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Did anybody face this problem? Why activity may be destroyed before get result?
Is there safe place to put my observer and handler (if activity isnt safe)?

Comment: Hmmmm are you rotating the phone in the other activity? Orientation changes destroy/recreate the activity.

Comment: Yes, problem is related with orientation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the launchmode. When I used external activities for results and setting the result the result code was always cancel when I used singleTop as a launch mode. Changing it to IE standard worked like a charm. Might be worth a try.